API request Azure DevOps, add group to a new project with automate flow
My flow gives me a 401 error:

The user is not authorized to access this resource.

Do you have an idea about the problem?
I am currently trying to add an administrator group and a contributor group to the project that I created via the flow via an automaton flow. To do this I retrieve the id of my project, then the id of my group via:
-> GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups/{groupDescriptor}?api-version =6.0-preview.1
with the groupDescriptor filled, then I take the origin id to then make this request to add a group:
-> PATCH https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/groupentitlements/{groupId}?api- version=7.1-preview.1 with this request body:
[ 
  {
    "from": "",
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/projectEntitlements",
    "value": {
      "projectRef": {
        "id": ""
      },
      "group": {
        "groupType": "ProjectContributor"
      }
    }
  } 
] 


The Group Entitlements rest api is used to manage Group Licensing Rules, not a common group from your 1st rest api.

To add the group as project administrator or contributor, you can use rest api Memberships - Add.
PUT https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/memberships/{subjectDescriptor}/{containerDescriptor}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
subjectDescriptor is the target descriptor from your 1st rest api.

containerDescriptor is the Contributor or Administrator group in the project.




Thank you very much for this answer which helps me enormously. I have easy access to my subjectDescriptor. The problem is that to recover the containerDescriptor it is a project that we create from an application, which triggers an automaton flow. I manage to retrieve the basic information about my project but I cannot access the list of groups of the project that I have just created, to retrieve the descriptor of [xxxxxx]\Project Administrators.

Glad to help! I notice you have raised a new ticket about the project group list and their descriptor, and it's already answered, please have a check.
